# How to make for each model a separate window?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I want my models to be loaded into two separate display areas, but I doubt the correctness of my chosen path. I think that I need to create my own separate "viewerDiv" for each model and load it there using the method "new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D (viewerDiv, {});". Is there another way to achieve this?
However, on the implementation of this idea, I came to sweat a lot and there is no result so far, because I cannot change the grind of the necessary block, because it is located in the file at [viewer3D.min.js](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js). I tried to download this file and change the desired property locally, but it turned out that this file works in conjunction with other files that I also need to download. Unfortunately I could not download these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT download the Viewer library or modify its code since that's against the user license and technically challenging to localize the library in its entirety with all its dynamic dependencies and resources - always reference the library at its CDN address.

See [this live sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/5gx69s14/) for multiple Viewer instances cohabiting together - simply initialize your Viewer instances separately to their corresponding containers and adjust the size of your canvases by its class name `adsk-viewing-viewer`

```
<style>
.adsk-viewing-viewer{width:50%!important}
</style>
<script>
var viewer1 = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv1);
var viewer2 = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv2);
...
</script>
```

Alternatively since Viewer 6+ the library offers a built in [Split Screen extension](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.SplitScreenExtension.html) using sub canvases for multiple models:

```
var options = {  viewports: [
            modelId => modelId == 1,
            modelId => modelId == 2, 
            modelId => modelId == 3,  
            modelId => modelId == 4]
     };
viewer.start();
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.SplitScreen', options).then(()=>{
    viewer.loadModel(svf1);
    viewer.loadModel(svf2);
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I looked at the first example and noticed that when you change the position in the first window, the position in the second one also changes. I need the changes in the first window not to affect the second. I would be glad if you tell me how this is possible (if in general this is possible).

Comment: Combine container ID into your selector to specify styling separately like `#myContainerID .adsk-viewing-viewer`. Consult a friend/colleague with more exposure to front end dev to help you out with the basics.

Comment: Maybe you meant [it](https://jsfiddle.net/cpvs1omh/)? In this case, the movement in the first block changes the position in the second, which I do not need.

Comment: Not it doesn't change the second - see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/d9n18esp/). As this is outside of the scope of the Viewer library itself can you consult a a friend/colleague with more exposure to front end dev as I suggested earlier?

Comment: is it possible to isolate elements only in one of the subcanvases if one is using the same model loaded in 2 canvases?